# confused with different commands for syncing repo

Tags: command-line, repository, github

I want to know the difference between following two commands at (A) and (B).

1. `<default revision="refs/heads/cm-12.0"
   remote="github"
   sync-c="true"
   sync-j="4" />`
2. `repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm12.0`

When I give the first command, after `cd ~/FOlder_Name/android/system`, I find the cursor is only blinking and nothing happens on the terminal screen. Am I doing right or wrong? I am confused.

Comment: I added quotes; the < and > make it a html  tag ;) 1 more thing: 1. is not a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first "command" is indeed to not command at all, it's a small chunk of the  [default.xml](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android/blob/cm-12.0/default.xml) file, the android manifest.

The second command as explained in the CyanogenMod [README](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android/blob/cm-12.0/README.mkdn) will initialize your local repository using the CyanogenMod trees.

Your cursor was blinking because your shell was interpreting the "<" as a redirection directive (and it waits for input), see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html.

Comment: **Prasanna:** As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Prasanna: You now have the ability to vote on answers too, just click the (^) mark. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to upvote too (corrected!)  **;-)**